# use a \foreach counter within \visible in Beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays, foreach

I am trying to sequentially show the parts of a TikZ drawing made using a  `\foreach` loop.

The code is the following:

```
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,calc,fit,shapes}

\begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}  

        \foreach \x in {1,...,6} {
          \visible<\x+2->{
          \node[] at (\x*0.75,0) (n\x) {$\x$};
          \foreach \y in {1,...,\x} {
            \node[] (p\x\y) [below = 0.3 + 0.3*\y of n\x]  {$\bullet$};
          }}}

        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that I want the `\visible` command counter to be delayed two units with respect to the counter `\x`. And LaTeX does not seem to recognize any of the following syntax:

- `\visible<\x+2>`
- `\visible<$\x+2$>`
- `\visible<(\x+2)>`
- `\visible<$(\x+2)$>`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beamer overlay cannot directly evaluate expressions like `\x+2`. So you'll have to help it a little bit by adding

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\z{\x+2}
```

and use `\z` in specifying the overlay. Also, note that you're missing a `positioning` library in your preamble.

## Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,calc,fit,shapes,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}  
  \foreach \x in {1,...,6} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\z{\x+2}
    \visible<\z->{
    \node[] at (\x*0.75,0) (n\x) {$\x$};
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\x} {
      \node[] (p\x\y) [below = 0.3 + 0.3*\y of n\x]  {$\bullet$};
    }}}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a slight variation of @Herr K. answer, I like using the `evaluate` in the loop. Easier to manipulate vs "pgfthingy" (pgftruncate and co)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,calc,fit,shapes,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}  
  \foreach %
        [evaluate ={\z = int(\x+2);}] %%%%%% <- here %%%%%%%
        \x in {1,...,6} {
    
    \visible<\z->{
    \node[] at (\x*0.75,0) (n\x) {$\x$};
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\x} {
      \node[] (p\x\y) [below = 0.3 + 0.3*\y of n\x]  {$\bullet$};
    }}}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```